# Laptop Heating in ubuntu , no issue in windows what to do?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, power-management, overheating, msi

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside windows in msi GS75 Stealth-243(Intel® Core™ i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz × 12, Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)). I'm experiencing unusual heating issues when I'm on the Linux while on Windows everything works fine. While Using Ubuntu heating starts and withing 5-10 minutes.

What I did till now 1. Updated thermald 2. Installed TLP 3. Installed cpufreq for toggling between performance and power save mode. Nothing has worked till now.I don't know whether people just say these all work or I am doing something wrong/ not able to use them properly. Please help. I never thought about the heating issue before buying the laptop[ Now I am very unhappy abt this].

1. Problem might not be because of the fans etc because everything is good and normal while using windows.
2. Since the laptop has come with pre-installed Windows, Few posts said about that saying there might not be correct drivers for ubuntu as all drivers were thought nd designed for windows. I understood that statement a bit but ok. If so then what to do, I mean how to solve that driver issue.
3. Are the graphic cards running by default? Nd that is causing the heating issue? If so how can I make the system stop using graphic card when not required. I mean even while just surfing google etc its getting heated up.
4. I need this dual boot system , so what can be done to reduce this heating issue,
   [Temperature values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aaCi.png)
   I really need help in this issue, please suggest me how to solve this issue. Atleast to reduce the temperature.
5. Until which limit Cooling pads works? I mean how much temperature it can reduce.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: maybe software rendering? `grep /dri /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Comment: ok. but what to do then?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default video drivers under Ubuntu?  Sometimes the custom drivers from the video card manufacturer are actually unstable and cause heat problems.

use the

```
    dmesg | less
```

command and look for anything that says it taints the kernel. This is often a big clue that you have installed custom drivers.

Also, what sort of laptop did you use, and how much memory do you have?

Are you using SSDs or spinning disk drives?

What is the output of the

```
    swapon -s
```

command (shows swap space allocated and used)

What is the output of the

```
    w
```

command (shows the load on your system)

what is the output of the

```
    df -h
```

command (shows the disk free on your root partition)

Comment: System Memory (RAM): 16GB I Solid State Drive Capacity: 1TB
Processor: 2.6 gigahertz Intel 9th Generation Core i7-9750H
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 Max-Q 8GB GDDR6

Comment: Filename(/dev/nvme0n1p5 )  Type(partition) Size(31250428)  Used(0)   Priority (-2)

Comment: /dev/loop0       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9993
/dev/loop1      384K  384K     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/550
/dev/loop3       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/simplescreenrecorder/1
/dev/loop2      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/100
/dev/loop5      161M  161M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop4       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1932

Comment: /dev/loop7      2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/utorrent/92
/dev/loop6       74M   74M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-3-stable/6
/dev/loop9      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/100

Comment: Hi Rani --because of your swap space showing Used(0), I don't think your system is overloading its memory.  Having 16 GB of RAM and fast processor are also good.

Comment: I had hoped to see something from the  w command.  Mine shows 21:19:46 up  1:19,  1 user,  load average: 0.68, 0.79, 1.39
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
steve    :0       :0               20:00   ?xdm?  36:42   0.00s /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session --run-script env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu /usr/bin/gnome-session --systemd --se

Comment: The three numbers after load average are what I'd like to see in the w command if you can report them here, it would help me diagnose things.

Comment: 15:44:04 up 5 min,  1 user,  load average:( 0.78, 0.71, 0.34)  TTY (0)  FROM(0)             LOGIN@(21:09)   IDLE (?xdm?)  JCPU(22.28s)   PCPU(0.00s) WHAT(/usr/lib/gdm3/g)

Answer (score 0):

Rani --
I was thinking that you could review BIOS settings and possibly apply updates when I found this on another forum.

https://www.infofuge.com/complete-msi-gs75-stealth-overheating-problem-fix/

If you hear fans, then that might be evidence of overheating that the fans can't even overcome.

Even if it's not a Windows problem, your Windows configuration could be at risk if heat damages the system when running Ubuntu.

If your laptop is under warranty, you might contact technical support to talk about BIOS settings.

Good luck,
mondotofu

Answer (score 0):

Answering on 4: I have a similar MSI and I had thermal problems (~70°C idle) on windows, that's when I decided to undervolt CPU (with Throttlestop) and also lower the Intel Power Boosts, since then my idle is <50°C. I then dual booted into Linux and while on Ubuntu 20.04 thermals are similar to those of windows, probably because of the undervolt. So look into that, undervolting is perfectly safe and may extend your laptop's life as high temperatures can wear it down. [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/MSILaptops/comments/j61c10/how_to_undervolt_msi_gl65/) seems like a good start.

Answering on 5: I also bought a Cooler Master aluminum cooling pad. I think these are useful mostly in the summer, especially if you live in a hot region. I experimented by plugging and unplugging the cooler, (on Windows) while looking at MSI afterburner temperatures and didn't see any visible differences on the trendline, so I don't think you'll see any difference on temperatures, but it's better than nothing. Also avoid putting the laptop on surfaces such as blankets, treat it like it's a desktop.